# drawing in android studio it's not the same in my phone

Tags: android

[Drawing in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST6WD.png)
[drawing in my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCEMY.jpg)

Comment: Please show the code of the layout of this file (.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using constraint layout, constraints must be added to each and every component. If you check the code for the XML layout, you will see the below error:

> This view is not constrained. It only has design time positions, so it
>   will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

Provide the constraints to each element. Shown below example for the ImageView
[image: constraint]